# jquery - go to next table row based on class name from current row location?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get the current row using this code. The "this" is a link in a table cell in the row.

```
$currentTR = $(this).parents('tr');
```

These next two lines can do the same thing, get the tr after the current row.

```
$nextTR = $(this).parents('tr').next();  
$nextTR = $(this).parents('tr').next('tr');
```

If I output `$nextTR.html()` I see what I expect

I don't know how many rows I need to go to get to the correct row except by class name and doing it like this doesn't work for me.

```
$nextTR = $(this).parents('tr').next('.concept');  
$nextTR = $(this).parents('tr').next('tr .concept');
```

All I get is null

The example on docs.Jquery [link text](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next#expr) uses this

```
$("p").next(".selected").css("background", "yellow");
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The .next(<selector>) filters the siblings. If the sibling fits the selector it is kept; otherwise it is filtered out.
In your case this means that if the very next sibling of the tr is of concept class, it is returned, otherwise you will get a null.

Comment: I see what you mean, duh I am still trying to get the NEXT row!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) a shot. Example from the documentation:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>nextAll demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #abc;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  div.after {
    border-color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>first</div>
<div>sibling<div>child</div></div>
<div>sibling</div>
<div>sibling</div>
<script>
$( "div" ).first().nextAll().addClass( "after" );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Crap, I was going to come up with a fancy solution using the new `index` function, but `$(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr.concept').eq(0) seems like a winner`. :)

Comment: So this makes sense. Does nextAll go to the bottom of the page from current position and then start back at the top of the dom and come back to the start position,  and that is how many elements get returned?

Comment: @Breadtruck - no. In your example nextAll returns all rows after the "current" row.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to recreate your html + javascript [at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ivuso) and I can reproduce the problem:

`siblings()` returns all 4 rows, and I can see that two of the rows have `class="concept"`, but `next('.concept')` does not return anything.

Isn't next() supposed to be a subset of siblings() ?

---

thanks for the comment, now I get it! I need silbings, not next.

Comment: next only returns the next element. If the selector you send into your call to next doesn't match the next element your result set will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the next one that is of a certain class?

You could try doing .next() and then checking the class perhaps?

I'm slightly confused about your question, i'll admit, because you seem to have provided your own answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that, you have HTML something like below:

**HTML:**

```
<tr class="current_tr"> <!-- This is your current tr -->
...
.....
...
</tr>

<tr class="nextRowClass"> <!-- You need to find this tr with the class-->
...
.....
...
</tr>
```

**JS:**

```
var current_row = $('tr.current_tr');
//You can get next row with the class as below
var next_row_with_class = $(current_row).next("tr.nextRowClass");
```